# What is the best alternative to polling a database for a value?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax, http

I have a Javascript web app and I am using Node.JS as the server component.

I want to integrate my app with a database. This database has a table with a field called 'status' which can change frequently (every couple of minutes or so).

I want my web app to know what the value of the status field is in real time.

**My Current Method:**

I currenlty, have an AJAX function in Javscript which sends a HTTP request to my Node.js server. The Node.js sever selects the record from the database and then returns the result to the AJAX function, which displays the result on the screen. I have setup an interval to execute the function every second.

This doesn't seem like a great option and it is causing a LOT of traffic on my server.

What is the proper way to monitor the SQL field in real time?

Comment: Why not keep the variable in memory and avoid polling the database at all?  On status change, update the value in memory and in the database.  This is contingent on your use case and resources

Comment: I don't control the status change. This field is from a third party database. I need MY app to know what the value is.

Comment: Third party database?  You have direct access to it?  How else would you know when something has been updated without checking, or refreshing the connection for them to push it to you?  If it's a database you manage, I recommend checking out Firebase, otherwise, I am curious to see what others say.  Seems like a simple setup with a web socket and memory management.

Comment: Are there multiple clients interested in this one value or are there multiple clients each with their own query that they are interested in?

Comment: Where'd you go?  It's been a week and no response.  It tried to help with some questions and an answer, but it seems you just disappeared.  That's not how you should be using this site.

Answer (score 2):

If all your clients are interested in the same value in the database and your database situation prevents any non-polling scenario, then you will want to move the polling from the client to the server so the server can poll ONCE for all the clients.  This will dramatically limit the load on both your server and on the database server.

Then, you can have each client connect to the server with a webSocket (or socket.io) connection and when the value in the database changes (and only then), you can then send an update message to each client over the webSocket connection.  This will use a ton less sever CPU and bandwidth and client battery.